# FosRestbundle keeps sending text/html as response and we are expecting json.

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

Here is our controller:

```
function getLocationsAction(Request $request) {

        $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
        $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Location')->select('name', 'state', 'country', 'coordinates');
        $locations = $query->getQuery()->execute();

        $data = array(
            'success' => true,
            'locations' => $locations,
            'displaymessage' => $locations->count() . " Locations Found"
        );

        $view = View::create()->setStatusCode(200)->setData($data);
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
```

Here is the config.yml for fosrestbundle:

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
```

Here is the route:

```
MainClassifiedBundle_get_locations:
    pattern:  /locations/
    defaults: { _controller: MainClassifiedBundle:ClassifiedCrudWebService:getLocations, _format:json}
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

Why are we getting text/html ? Ho wcan we force the response to be application/json?

Please help as this is causing huge pains at the moment

Comment: Since there is a `->setStatusCode()`, there's probably also a method for setting the response mime type. Isn't there a manual?

Comment: FosRestBundle by default is supposed to do JSON however my server keeps sending text/html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating your view statically and have not enabled any listeners.

This way there is no format guessing involved.

Pass the format as argument to your function and set the format on the View object:

```
function getLocationsAction(Request $request, $_format) {
{
    // ...
    $view = View::create()
         ->setStatusCode(200)
         ->setData($data)
         ->setFormat($_format)   // <- format here
    ;
    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

See the documentation chapter [The View Layer](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md).

---

If you want automatic format guessing you have to enable the **listeners**.

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
```

Read more in the chapter [Listener Support](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#step-3-listener-support).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you cant rely on the $_format (in my case) you can explicitly set the format like so:

```
    public function createAction(Request $request): Response
{
    // ...

    return $this->viewHandler->handle(View::create($json)->setFormat('json'));
}
```